# Javascript validate string regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this validate functions:

```
function unformat (value) {
  if (!value) {
    return '';
  }

  return value.replace(/^0+|[^0-9kK]+/g, '').toUpperCase();
}


function validate(value) {
  const unformatted = unformat(value);

  if (/^0+/.test(unformatted)) {
    return false;
  }

  let remainer = parseInt(unformatted.slice(0, -1), 10);
  let module = 1;
  let counter = 0;

  while (remainer > 0) {
    module = (module + (remainer % 10) * (9 - counter++ % 6)) % 11;
    remainer = Math.floor(remainer / 10);
  }

  const verifier = module > 0 ? '' + (module - 1) : 'K';

  return verifier === unformatted.slice(-1);

}

console.log(validate('14.211.109-8-')); // true, it should be false
console.log(validate('14.211.109-8 ')); // true, it should be false
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/0nb51myp/5/

The idea is ot get `false` in two case when right now is getting `true`:

1. When the string ends in ``  // -
2. When the string ends in    // blankspace

How could I modify that validate function?

Comment: `if (/^.*[-\s]$/.test(value)) return false;`?

Comment: nope, still returns true

Comment: you need to put it right after `function validate(value) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like:

```
const validate = (value) => {

    if (!/^.*[-\s]$/.test(value)) {
      return false;
    }

    const unformatted = unformat(value);


    let remainer = parseInt(unformatted.slice(0, -1), 10);
    let module = 1;
    let counter = 0;

    while (remainer > 0) {
      module = (module + (remainer % 10) * (9 - counter++ % 6)) % 11;
      remainer = Math.floor(remainer / 10);
    }

    const verifier = module > 0 ? '' + (module - 1) : 'K';

    return verifier === unformatted.slice(-1);

  }

  console.log(validate('14.211.109-8-')); // it should return false
  console.log(validate('14.211.109-8 ')); // it should return false
  console.log(validate('14.211.109-8')); // it should return true
```

Comment: I picked this answer as the correct one, but now I'm trying to find a way to return false when a blankspace in the beggining is present

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check at the beginning of the function:

```
if(/[ -]$/.test(value)) return false;
```

```js
function unformat (value) {
  if (!value) {
    return '';
  }

  return value.replace(/^0+|[^0-9kK]+/g, '').toUpperCase();
}


function validate(value) {
  if(/[ -]$/.test(value)) return false;
  const unformatted = unformat(value);

  if (/^0+/.test(unformatted)) {
    return false;
  }

  let remainer = parseInt(unformatted.slice(0, -1), 10);
  let module = 1;
  let counter = 0;

  while (remainer > 0) {
    module = (module + (remainer % 10) * (9 - counter++ % 6)) % 11;
    remainer = Math.floor(remainer / 10);
  }

  const verifier = module > 0 ? '' + (module - 1) : 'K';

  return verifier === unformatted.slice(-1);

}

console.log(validate('14.211.109-8-')); // true, it should be false
console.log(validate('14.211.109-8 ')); // true, it should be false
```

Comment: And if has a blankspace at the begining?

Comment: @pmiranda What do you want to return in that case?

Comment: that case, False too https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/0nb51myp/20/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to allow a space at the start or a space or - at the end, you can use an alternation `|` with a start `^` and end `$` anchor.

```
^ |[ -]$
```

If you want to match a whitespace char you can use `\s` but note that it can also match a newline.

```
^\s|[\s-]$
```

For example

```
if (/^ |[ -]$/.test(value)) {
    return false;
}
```

```js
function unformat(value) {
  if (!value) {
    return '';
  }

  return value.replace(/^0+|[^0-9kK]+/g, '').toUpperCase();
}


function validate(value) {

  if (/^ |[ -]$/.test(value)) {
    return false;
  }

  const unformatted = unformat(value);

  if (/^0+/.test(unformatted)) {
    return false;
  }

  let remainer = parseInt(unformatted.slice(0, -1), 10);
  let module = 1;
  let counter = 0;

  while (remainer > 0) {
    module = (module + (remainer % 10) * (9 - counter++ % 6)) % 11;
    remainer = Math.floor(remainer / 10);
  }

  const verifier = module > 0 ? '' + (module - 1) : 'K';

  return verifier === unformatted.slice(-1);

}

console.log(validate('14.211.109-8-')); // false
console.log(validate('14.211.109-8 ')); // false
console.log(validate(' 14.211.109-8')); // false
console.log(validate('14.211.109-8')); // true
```